# Does ASP MVC use a cached production database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, caching

Someone changed my admin password that I use to login to my website.  I changed it back, and I can now log in to the MVC site on localhost.  However, it won't log in on the server when I publish the site out.  This happened yesterday, too, but eventually the production server started letting me log in again.  They both use the same database.  There seems to simply be a a time delay or some sort of caching going on here.  Does ASP MVC do something like this?  Does anyone know how to refresh it so that I can log in to both sites again?

Thank you.

Comment: There's no such functionality out of box, if you haven't implemented that by yourself. Asp.net mvc does not even use database by itself :)

Comment: No, I haven't implemented it in MVC.  Do you know if this could be implemented on the database server, itself?

Comment: The server *will* cache connections in a connection pool. To refresh, restart your application pool in IIS.

Comment: Mike thank you so much.  We had a meeting and needed this to be working.  Please submit your post as an answer so I can accept it.  Restarting the application pool worked!

Comment: Did you say you published the site to production and then couldn't log in? If thats the case your application pool would of been restarted anyways.

Comment: I don't know, but restarting it worked.

Comment: Hmm well at least it works I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question, as stated by Mike McCaughan, was this:

> The server will cache connections in a connection pool. To refresh,
>   restart your application pool in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Entity does have cache of it's own. But I think your problem depends on whether you enable it. 
So I suggest you learn more about the cache and check if you enabled it or not~

You can find more about Entity's cache [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jkowalski/archive/2009/06/11/tracing-and-caching-in-entity-framework-available-on-msdn-code-gallery.aspx)

Comment: As stated by Mike in the comments above, "The server will cache connections in a connection pool. To refresh, restart your application pool in IIS."  Thanks, anyway.